# How to include the values of a select statement in an insert? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I have this select statement:

```
select it.item_id
from item as it
where it.owning_collection in (select col.collection_id
from collection as col
where col.name like '%Restricted%'
```

Which returns around 3k results. Now I would like to make an insert in another table for each one of those results with that item_id as one of the parameters like this:

```
insert into metadatavalue (metadata_value_id, **item_id**, metadata_field_id, text_value, text_lang, place, confidence)
```

But since I'm not very experienced with databases, I'm not sure how to make these multiple inserts

All the other information needed in the insert statement are fixed values.

Table structures:

```
Table Item
*item_id
*submitter_id
*in_archive
*withdrawn
*last_modified
*owning_collection
*dicoverable

Table metadata
*metadata_value_id
*item_id
*metadata_field_id
*text_value
*text_lang
*place
*authority
*confidence
```

Comment: How do you get other columns?

Comment: the other columns are no problem, they will be fixed values

Comment: Do you mean that `item_id` is a column name in table `metadatavalue`? Or are you missing a `VALUES` or `SELECT` clause in the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: yes, and that is the data I'm getting from the select statement.
I just didn't include the VALUES part of the statement since I'm not sure if that is how it should be solved

Comment: If `item_id` is a column name,then where do you get the values to insert from?

Comment: Please post the structure of the `metadatavalue` table.

Comment: I added the tables structure in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into metadatavalue (metadata_value_id, item_id, metadata_field_id, text_value, text_lang, place, confidence)
select 'metadata_value_id',it.item_id,'metadata_field_id','text_value', 'text_lang', 'place', 'confidence'
from item it
where it.owning_collection in (select col.collection_id
from collection as col
where col.name like '%Restricted%')
```

Replace 'apostrophed' columns with its default values.

[Further reading](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-insert.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked like a charm! I just had to make some minor tweaks. There is a parenthesis missing at the end of the statement and I removed metadata_value_id since that was an autoincremental value

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO metadatavalue (item_id, metadata_field_id, text_value, text_lang, place, confidence)
  SELECT it.item_id, <c1>, <c2>, <c3>, <c4>, <c5>
  FROM item AS it
  JOIN collection AS col ON col.collection_id = it.owning_collection
  WHERE col.name LIKE '%Restricted%'
```

Where you replace `<c1>` etc with your constant values. Note also that I have rewritten your `SELECT` query to a more efficient `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now know how to make a multiple insert for values obtained from a query! And I will try that optimization next time! You've been really helpful

Comment: Your welcome! Look into the `JOIN` clauses on the `SELECT` documentation page, it is generally much faster than a filter on `WHERE somecolumn IN (subquery)`.